# Kotlin generic inheritance

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin, type-mismatch

I have a problem and can't resolve it. I have an interface `Presenter` which is generic and take any subtype of interface `MvpView`

```
interface Presenter<in V : MvpView> {
    fun attachView(view: V)
    fun detachView()
}
```

Then I have another
 abstract class `BasePresenter` which is subtype of `Presenter`

```
abstract class BasePresenter<V : MvpView> : Presenter<V> {

    protected var mvpView: V? = null
        protected get

    override fun attachView(view: V) {
        this.mvpView = view
    }

    override fun detachView() {
        mvpView = null
    }
}
```

And I have a class

```
abstract class BaseMvpActivity<P : BasePresenter<T>, T : MvpView> : BaseActivity(), MvpView {

    @Inject lateinit protected var presenter: P

    protected abstract fun inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        inject()
        initPresenter(savedInstanceState)
    }

    protected fun initPresenter(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        presenter.attachView(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        presenter.detachView()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

And there I have an error when try to call `presenter.attachView(this)`

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is BaseMvpActivity<P, T> but T was expected
```

I also tried to do like this `abstract class BaseMvpActivity<P : BasePresenter<*>> : BaseActivity()` but also have  an error like `Type mismatch: inferred type is BaseMvpActivity<P> but Nothing was expected`

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: attachView() expects a T as argument. You're passing `this`. `this` is not of generic type T. It isn't even an MvpView, which T is supposed to implement.

Comment: Look, I should pass to this method any subtype of  `MvpView`. My `BaseMvpActivity` implement this interface. So whats wrong?

Comment: Look, no, it didn't implement this interface until your edit, 26 seconds ago. But even then. A List<T extends Number> only accepts T. You can't add an Int or a Double to such a list, even though Int and Double extend Number, because Int and Double aren't the same type as T.

Comment: My `BaseActivity` implements `MvpView`. I've just edited to make it more evident. Yes, you're right about the list analogy. So how can I make this code compilable?

Comment: `abstract class BaseMvpActivity<P : BasePresenter<BaseMvpActivity<P>>>` would compile.

Comment: Yes, it will compile, but it won't let me pass subclasses of `BasePresenter` as a type of any activity which will extend `BaseMvpActivity`. For example 

`interface MainMvpView : MvpView`,

`class MainPresenter : BaseMvpPresenter<MainMvpView>()`

and I can't use 

`class MainActivity : BaseMvpActivity<MainPresenter>(), MainMvpView`

Comment: @RamanBranavitski have a look at my answer. While trying to figure out your code, I came across that, this case is not working in Kotlin i guess. I have run both of the code but kotlin gives compile time error.

Comment: Yes, I've looked. But I don't think it's a Kotlin issue:) The only way I make my code work is to use `abstract class BaseMvpActivity<P : BasePresenter<*>> : BaseActivity()` and call `presenter.attachView(this)` method not in this abstract class, but in it's subclasses. But it forces me to write this line of code in all subclasses of `BaseMvpActivity`

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to make `BasePresetner` generic as you are not going to return a value of that generic type. We use generics to prevent type casts of returning value from a method and prevent possible Cast exceptions.

What i want to say that you do not need to make `BasePresenter` generic. Just declare mvpView as MvpView and use its methods. Suppose if you do make it generic, no plus point you are going to achieve because you will still have access to MvpView's method only(Not the `sub-class`).

```
abstract class BasePresenter : Presenter<V> {

    protected var mvpView: MvpView = null
        protected get

    override fun attachView(view: MvpView) {
        this.mvpView = view
    }

    override fun detachView() {
        mvpView = null
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Java code only compiles (with a warning), because you're using a raw type instead of properly typing tour variable. Replace `MvpViewSubClass class1 = new MvpViewSubClass<P>();` by `MvpViewSubClass<P> class1 = new MvpViewSubClass<>();`, and it won't compile either, as expected.

Comment: ohh.. my bad.. let me figure out then

Comment: @JBNizet i have changed answer, please check and let me know, what do you think about it.